# Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script

Tags: vbscript

I get the following error message when I run the vbscript named 'GetDiskSize.vbs' in Windows 2008 Server.

**Can't find script engine "VBScript" for script 'GetDiskSize.vbs'**

The vbscript has been registreed as regsrv32 VBScript.dll but still not work.  Please help.

Regards,
Wilson

Comment: This video had helped me, which handles 2 types of issues : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gix_hB8nXfU

Answer (score 2):

The usual fix would be to reregister the dll:

```
regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\vbscript.dll
```

But you mention you've tried that.

Some Antivirus products insert themselves in the registry so that they get called as the scripting engine before passing on to the vbscript/jscript engine.  It could be that this has caused problems.  Try uninstalling your antivirus to test if this is the case.

See useful post here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/instan/archive/2010/07/20/can-t-find-script-engine-quot-vbscript-quot-for-script-after-installing-ms10-020.aspx

If all else fails, and you're on Windows XP you could try reinstalling WSH 5.6:

Download from: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C717D943-7E4B-4622-86EB-95A22B832CAA&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

so I had the same problem for the longest time and I just realized why:

I had associated vbs files with Notepad++ and that's why it didn't work! After removing the association, vbs apps finally work again!

Comment: I know this is 10 years old but maybe someone finds this useful. I hope!